# gud opening source in gud interaction window

Tags: window, gud

When debugging with gud and gdb in many-windows mode, some source files are opened in the gud interaction window instead of the source window.

This appears to happen to files, and only those files, which were open in Emacs before gud was started.

I've replicated the behavior without my environment using `emacs -Q`

This is currently in version 24.5.1 but I also experienced the behavior in 24.4.

My bug report is here: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22374

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having similar issue with 24.5.1 which comes with Ubuntu 16 LTS.

Seems to be somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560933/how-to-turn-off-input-output-buffer-in-gud) issue and using "gud-gdb" command as [suggested in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559663/956967) to revert to the old GUD behavior solved my problem.

And within that issue, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578246/956967) describes the issue of the usage of "dedicated window" with new GUD in more details.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with `gdb-many-windows`. My window and buffer setup was always messed after certain events. I decided to rewrite it myself, so I can also customize my window setup better. You have to take a look at the relations between `gdb-many-windows`, `gdb-restore-windows` and `gdb-setup-windows`.

If you only want to fix your problem with the source file, you should
look for this snippet `(gud-find-file gdb-main-file)`. This is actually responsible for opening your source file. However there seems to be a problem with the code that uses it.

So far it works for me just fine, though I expect different problems, because I've removed some code.

**EDIT:**
I just recognized, that there seems to be a problem with `gud-find-file`. However I couldn't fix it yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `gud-find-file`. I'll look there for a possible work-around or fix.